# Auto Login Facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook

autologin facebook in my app if some one has logged in fb in iphone. Thats is my doesnt ask for credentials to user if facebook a/c has been logged in any app or on iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
- (void)fbDidLogout
{
    //NSLog(@"facebook did logout");

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
    //////NSLog(@"facebook did logout");
    [self showLoggedOut:YES];
    logoutButton.hidden=YES;

}
```

it may help you

Comment: Sir its misundertood i want that if anyone has logged in any native app in iphone with facebook then my app pic up user credentials its self and get logged in with those credentials

Comment: In iphone and ipod it wil login automatically

Comment: :-- And whats the method to check the cache of webview to retrieve the access token , without being asked to enter the credentials in app if i have loged in fb in my iphone. Please do help i am unable to find the solution , i used fb graph class to get the access token .